# kendogrid filter multi true vertical

Tags: jquery, css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

[image]

I am using a jquery kendogrid

Trying to change the filter popup to show vertically instead of horizantally.

Please help me with the style that can show vertically instead of horizontally.

Comment: Show your code to generate the grid with filter as shown in your image. Even better, create a DOJO/Codepen.

Comment: Like @ezanker says, we really need to see your code before we can help. But I have a theory which I'm posting as an answer, below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this [demo](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/filter-multi-checkboxes) it appears that the behaviour you want is the default behaviour of a column configured with `filterable: { multi: true }`. It's only when you add an `itemTemplate` that you have to deal with the markup yourself. So for example, this column collection should all behave the way you want:

```
columns: [
  { field: "ProductName", filterable: { multi: true, search: true} },
  { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: 120, filterable: { multi: true } },
  { field: "UnitsInStock", title: "Units In Stock", width: 120, filterable: { multi: true } }
]
```

If you were using an `itemTemplate` removing it should solve your problem.

Hope this helps.